# Aligning div to center and its content to the left

Tags: html, css, position, centering

I'd like to have a div that is centered on the document. The div should take all the space it can to display the content and the content itself should be aligned to the left.

What I want to create is image gallery with rows and columns that are center and when you add a new thumb it will be aligned to the left.

Code:

```
<div id="out">
    <div id="inside">
        <img src="http://www.babybedding.com/fabric/solid-royal-blue-fabric.jpg"/>   
        <img src="http://www.babybedding.com/fabric/solid-royal-blue-fabric.jpg"/>   
        <img src="http://www.babybedding.com/fabric/solid-royal-blue-fabric.jpg"/>   
        <img src="http://www.babybedding.com/fabric/solid-royal-blue-fabric.jpg"/>   
        <img src="http://www.babybedding.com/fabric/solid-royal-blue-fabric.jpg"/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
img {
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    margin: 5px;
}

#out {
    width: 100%;
}

#inside {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
    background: #e2e2f2;
}
```

Live version here: http://jsfiddle.net/anPF2/10/
As you will notice, on right side of "#inside" there is space that I want to remove, so this block will be displayed until the last square and all of it will be centered aligned.

**EDIT:**
Please view this photo: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qy6trnmdks73hy5/css.jpg
It explains better what I'm trying to get.

**EDIT 2:**
I've uloaded another photo to show how it should adjust on lower resolution screens. notice the margins on the left and right. This is what I'm trying to get (unsuccessfully so far :\ )
https://www.dropbox.com/s/22zp0otfnp3buke/css2.jpg

***EDIT 3 / ANSWER***
well, thank you everybody for trying solve my problem. I solved this problem using JS, with a function that listens to a screen resize event. The functions checks the size of the right margin and add padding to the left so all the content is centered. I didn't find a solution using CSS. If you have one, I'd very much like to know it.

Thanks eveyone!

Comment: Fiddle not showing CSS

Comment: "The div should take all the space it can" - How is it going to be centred if it's taking up all the available space?

Comment: my thoughts exactly... I think he means, he wants it to be centered whilst being able to add 2,3,4 etc images and still have those centered...

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I didn't explain well. Please see this photo: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qy6trnmdks73hy5/css.jpg

Comment: Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anPF2/43/).

Comment: Thanks Mr_Green but this is kind of cheating :) I'll lose the proportions of the image I'll be displaying.

Comment: give min-width and max-width to the parent element. that should solve your problem :)

Comment: Can you add the pictures to post or make it accessible, to see if anyone after so long can fix, I need exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a `width` for `#inside` to center it. I used `width: 120px`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anPF2/7/

Additionally, CSS should be used for the height and width of images, not attributes such as `height="300"`. The fiddle reflects this change.

Answer (score 0):

use of `display:inline-block` takes extra margins. To remove those set `font-size:0px` to the `#out` container. See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GKqSX/)

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work for me. Can you look on the link for the photo I just added?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Pixels when laying out your css, it makes it very rigid and causes possible problems for people with high resolution screens and low resolution screens. Its best to declare it as a % or em (% is still probably slightly better when working with widths, but em for height is perfect)

First, the "outer" div must be declared to be smaller than what it is inside. For instance if "outer" is inside body:

```
#outer{
    width: 100%;
}
#inside{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#inside img{
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    float: left;
}
```

Okay so, since "inside" is 80% of "outer"'s width, the margin-left:auto, margin-right: auto together make the "inside" div center within the "outer".

Setting the float property to left moves all the imgs of inside to always try to move left while it can.

EDIT: I fixed this after looking at your picture you provided.

I haven't tested this but I believe it should work, let me know if you are having more problems.

Comment: After seeing your picture: you want the width of "inside" to be 80% or something and margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto inside the #inside tag as well. You can declare the width of "outer" yourself, and the clear: both; is not necessary for the img tag. Everything else should make it work.

Comment: I want the width of the "#inside" div to have a width that depends on the user resolution. If it high enough to display 10 images, then be it and if only 5 then 5. I tried your code but I'm still getting the annoying margin on the right :-\

Comment: float: left; means if there is no space in the div to the right, it will move to the next line and make the div longer

Comment: Thanks again but it's still not working. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/anPF2/42/ - change the width of the preview window and see that when you resize, the div doesn't center itself.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about the margin on the right. Unfortunately I don't think it is possible to fix under every circumstance. You see when you images, they are of fixed size, width and height. Once you declare something of fixed size, using tags that are relative and floating becomes unpredictable.

For instance, once you resize the screen by a small amount, the width may not be enough to fit another full image on, perhaps only 60% of the image, so the image goes down to the next line, leaving a disproportionate gap on the right hand side.

The is unavoidable for all circumstance

Comment: Using that jsfiddle you can see my point, if you adjust the "result" width, at a certain point it looks how you want it to, but then once you move it past that point either way it goes out of whack again.

Comment: Yea, you just described my problem. When there is not enough space for another image on a row, I do want it to go to a new row but I also want the container div to get smaller and centered. It seems kind of odd that you can't solve this with CSS. I can write some JS to fix this problem but I really wanted to avoid it so all styling won't be affected from the JS... :-/

And thank you very much for your help so far! :)

Comment: I would suppose the reason it cant be done (although maybe it can and I simply don't know how) is that css is just "suggestive" it tells the browser how it would like the page to look, you shouldn't ever try explicitly tell it how to look. when you use pictures and tags based on pixels you are doing just that, which makes the design less predictable to all users.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to achieve? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anPF2/26/)

```
img {
height: 110px;
width: 110px;
margin: 5px;
display: inline-block;
}

#out {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid red;
}

#inside {
position: relative;
background: #e2e2f2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I want :-/ I want to cut the extra space on the right side and then all the block to be centered (check the photo I uploaded)

Answer (score 0):

To make the boxes not go the entire width of the page, try setting the width less than 100% on `#out` and add `margin:auto;` to center it.

```
#out {
    width: 90%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anPF2/36/

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I wanted. I'd like to cut the right space on the right and make it go away, so if you have enough space (high screen res) for 10 images, you'll see 10 without the spacing.

Comment: I believe you'll need JavaScript for that. [This fiddle is close](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/anPF2/48/), but not quite perfect, especially at small sizes it seems.

Comment: Yep, had to use JS and it works well now. It's just a little weird that such a thing can't be accomplished by CSS.

Comment: If it can, it's beyond me presently. It works fine with `text-align:center`, but you want the trailing elements to the left. Hmm... I'll keep an eye out and make updates if I find anything.