# Centering a multiline horizontal UL without centered LI

Tags: html, css, html-lists, centering

I have a grid of square divs that are displayed as li in a ul where the ul is styled to be a multiline horizontal list. I want it so the UL is centered (as the number of items per line varies by device size) without having the individual LI centered (as seen in the second row of the diagram).

I've tried positioning them as relative inline-blocks, however that makes the last LI centered in the middle, which is not desirable.

```
ul
{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
li
{
    margin-left:5px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[image: Layout diagram]

Any suggestions that aren't screen-size dependent?

Comment: Please post your css/html. It is hard to give you a detailed response without it.

Comment: @asdf There is a lot of css that isn't relevant to the ul/lo, but this is the css styling for ul/li

Comment: You can’t horizontally center inline(-block) elements via auto margins; but `text-align:center` on the parent element will do the trick. (And then you “revert” it on the `ul` via `text-align:left`, so that the `li` stay aligned to the left as you want them to.)

Comment: @CBroe Making the UL a block and adding text-align:left did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @CBroe Actually I'm not sure. It appears centered on one device and not centered on a smaller device. I might need to play around more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know that can not be fully achieved, at certain resolutions will always be a space in right that you can't remove check out this: [Aligning div to center and its content to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773178/aligning-div-to-center-and-its-content-to-the-left)

[image]

Your best shout using pure css will be:

1- using `display: inline-block` and `text-align: left` as @CBroe said:

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
}
ul{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
}

li{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 7px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

2- using `position: absolute` and `transform`:

```css
ul{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

li{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 7px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

3- using `display: inline-block` and `float: left`:

```css
body{
    text-align: center;
}
ul{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 7px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

---

**Edit:**

If you are willing to use some `js` you can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   setWidth();
     $(window).resize(function(){
             setWidth()
     });
});

function setWidth(){
    var $ul = $('ul');
    var $li = $('li');

    $ul.css('width', 'auto');

    var ulWidth = $ul.outerWidth();
    var liWidth = $li.outerWidth();
    liWidth += parseInt($li.css('margin-left')) + parseInt($li.css('margin-right'));

    var div = Math.floor(ulWidth / liWidth);

    $ul.css('width', div * liWidth);
}
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
div{  
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 25px;
}
ul{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

li{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 7px;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>this is the div <br/>
 \|/ </p>
<div>
 <p>this is the ul <br/>
 \|/ </p>
  <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Notice that right now the `ul` is well centered inside the `div`.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to have the UL auto-resize so that there isn't that extra space at the end?

Comment: The list only auto-resize each time an item go to the line below.